# How to draw outer labels for polar chart using ng2-charts and chart.js at fixed positions outside the rings?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am drawing polar chart with chart.js `^2.8.0` and `ng2-charts ^2.3.0` in Angular. I have used `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` to display labels but this does not support lables outside at fixed positions outside the polar chart rings like this [plugin](https://github.com/robcrocombe/chartjs-plugin-outerLabels) for chart.js display labels outside the pie chart.

**CODE:**

```
myColors = [{ backgroundColor: ["rgb(203, 75, 75, 0.5)", "rgb(237, 194, 64, 0.5)", "rgb(175, 216, 248, 0.5)"] }];

ChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];

polarAreaChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
         color: '#000000',
         anchor: 'end',
         align: 'end',
         padding: 50,
         display: true,
         font: {
           weight: 'bolder'
         },
         formatter: function(value, ctx) {
          return `${ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex]} - ${value} %`;
       },
      },
    },
    scale: {
      ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 100,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 10
      },
      gridLines: {
        color: ['gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'red','gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray'],
        lineWidth: [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
      }
    }
  };
        
polarAreaChartType: ChartType = "polarArea";
```

**Markup**

```
<canvas id="polar-chart" baseChart height="40vh" width="120vw" 
                        [data]="polarAreaChartData" 
                        [labels]="polarAreaChartLabels"
                        [legend]="polarAreaLegend"
                        [plugins]="ChartPlugins"
                        [options]="polarAreaChartOptions"
                        [chartType]="polarAreaChartType" 
                        [colors]="myColors">        
                    </canvas>
```

[image: Actual Output]

Is there any plugin or addon to display the labels outside the rings in polar chart.js and ng2-charts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update to chart.js V3 you can use the build in pointLabels and center them:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        pointLabels: {
          display: true,
          centerPointLabels: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have added v3 along with v2 and using both versions. Only updating this polar chart as other v3 has breaking changes and most of the charts in app are based on v2. But still pointlabels are not being displayed.

Comment: Afaik you can't use both versions at the same time, so you are still using V2 then

Comment: one is through npm and other is through cdn. How can this be achieved. I cannot modify all charts to v3 as it has many breaking changes. i want to use v3 through cdn.

Comment: I have downloaded chart.js v3 and renamed the class variable to ChartVersionThree and put it in assets and included it as a script tag and called the particular function from version three. It is a work around but it is working.